OpenAi vue3 pinecone/zilliz php/laravel
what is the right way to implement search using vue3 or laravel/php via openai which is using pinecone/zilliz vector database?
i've read many information about all of this, everything in wirking well using python but not this stack

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I'm not a laravel/php user myself, but I google searched and found: https://github.com/openai-php/laravel
So you would take your top_k ANN search results from zilliz and stuff the chunk texts into the prompt you send to openai.
For a tutorial notebook how to do search on zilliz, see our bootcamp:  https://github.com/milvus-io/bootcamp/blob/master/bootcamp/Retrieval/imdb_metadata_json.ipynb
